# Using a separate PasteDeploy file for sqlAlchemy urls with cryptic passwords

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, config, pyramid

I have a Pyramid application I am working on.  I, ideally, need the ability to put the sqlalchemy url settings into a separate file, and then consume this file on the `engine_from_config` file.  By default, pserve just uses the .ini file you specify to call the `main()` method, e.g.:

```
def main(global_config, **settings):
    """
    This function returns a Pyramid WSGI application.
    """
```

How would I use a second ini file for settings which are stored in the same directory as the development.ini file?  example: **development_database.ini**

Second: the database usernames have very cryptic passwords, that contain percent % and parenthesis ( etc.  ConfigParser does not seem to like this and I don't know of an easy way to escape.  Is there a way around this?  I don't want to ask our DBA to have to change the password.

Comment: To use percentage in the .ini file, you can apply the patch from https://bitbucket.org/ianb/pastedeploy/issue/11/there-is-no-way-to-escape-character-in-the

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as you're going to the effort of making the passwords cryptic, it's a good idea to store them as environment variables, and keep them out of source control altogether. This also avoids using ConfigParser.

SQLAlchemy's engine_from_config function accepts arbitrary keyword args, and treats these exactly the same as any of the arguments it takes from the development.ini file

So if I have this in my system shell (bash in my case):

```
export DB_URL=postgresql+psycopg2://user:password@localhost:5432/mydb
```

My Pyramid code could look like this:

```
import os

db_url = os.environ['DB_URL']

def main(global_config, **settings):
    engine = engine_from_config(settings, 'sqlalchemy.', url=db_url)
    …
```

The engine_from_config function will take all arguments with the prefix 'sqlalchemy.' from the development.ini file, and takes my db_url as the all-important 'url' parameter.

**EDIT**

Sorry, I realised I didn't really answer the first part of the question. The neatest way to use multiple PasteDeploy files is with a use: directive:

```
[app:main]
use=config:another_config_file.ini
…
```

This is well documented here: http://pythonpaste.org/deploy/#config-uris

In this way you can 'chain' the .ini files, but they still won't help you with the cryptic passwords - for that you need environment variables as explained in the first half of my answer.

Comment: I forgot to accept this! I'm sorry.  The config:another_file.ini directive was very helpful as well. :)

Comment: Quite alright! Thanks for accepting; I'm glad it was useful.